# Redstone mapper with flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, redstone.dart

I want to use the [redstone mapper](https://github.com/redstone-dart/redstone_mapper) to decode Json to objects.
However flutter doesn't support mirrors and so I cannot initialize the mapper over the normal way with `bootstrapMapper();`

Therefore I looked it up, I have to use `staticBootstrapMapper(...)`

```
/**
     * initialize the mapper system.
     * 
     * This function provides a mapper implementation that
     * uses data generated by the redstone_mapper's transformer,
     * instead of relying on the mirrors API.
     * 
     */ 
    void staticBootstrapMapper(Map<Type, TypeInfo> types) {
      _staticTypeInfo = types;

      configure(_getOrCreateMapper, _createValidator);
    }
```

[Link to source code](https://github.com/redstone-dart/redstone_mapper/blob/master/lib/mapper_factory_static.dart)

I dont know what I should put into the map of `Map<Type, TypeInfo> types`.
Lets say I want to use **ObjectData** to transform json data to this object.
**But how do I have to use this initializing method?** Unfortunately I didnt find an example how to use this static bootstrap manager.

```
class ObjectData {
  @Field()
  @NotEmpty()
  DataType dateType; // might be a User object

  @Field()
  @NotEmpty()
  String id;

  @Field()
  @NotEmpty()
  List<String> versions;
}
```

Comment: I know its not the answer of your question but my be it could help: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/jaguar_serializer

Comment: Flutter won't support mirrors. You'll have to gi with a code generation solution.

Comment: Yep I think all of them (also /jaguar_serializer) are not working because they use mirrors and reflection. Therefore i want to use staticBootstrapMapper because it doesn't use mirrors. But I dont know how to initialize this method so that the framework translate all the static types into objects.

Comment: jaguar should work https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jF0kD7lxTTw look at 13:13

Comment: yep thanks its a great video ;) I will try it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mirrors isn't supported in Flutter, as noted above in comments.

You might want try alternative packages that don't rely on mirrors:

- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/json_serializable
- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/built_value

Of those two (and others) `json_serializable` looks like the easiest to get started, but might not have as many features.